# C# DataSet is not updated after modifying the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, controls

I am trying to update the data grid view (move a row to a new index).
I can't update it directly because the data grid view is bound so I am doing this using the dataTable.

```
  var dataTable = ((DataView)dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource).Table;
            var dataGridRow = dataGridViewWebFields.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(fieldName));
            if (dataGridRow != null && dataGridRow.Index != newIndex)
            {
                var dataTableRow = GetWebFieldFromDataGridViewRow(dataGridRow);
                var dataViewRow = dataGridViewWebFields.Rows[newIndex];
                dataViewRow.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridRow.DefaultCellStyle;
                var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = dataTableRow.ItemArray;
                dataTable.Rows.Remove(dataTableRow);
                dataTableRow.Index = newIndex;
                dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, newIndex);
                dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
            }
```

The problem is that after I am saving this to the database and refreshing the control, the state of the data grid view is back to the default (before the changes). I think that something is not updated correctly on the DataSet.
Can you guide me on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

put this code in the last line in your code
`dataGridRow.DataBind()`
`dataGridRow.Refresh()`

Comment: The dataGridRow is type DataGridViewRow and it doesn't have this method

Comment: I tried to use dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource = null; and dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource = dataTable;  This works for the first change but then I get an exception in second loop

Comment: try this
`dataGridRow.Refresh()`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
  var dataTable = ((DataView)dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource).Table;
            var dataGridRow = dataGridViewWebFields.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(fieldName));
            if (dataGridRow != null && dataGridRow.Index != newIndex)
            {
                var dataTableRow = GetWebFieldFromDataGridViewRow(dataGridRow);
                var dataViewRow = dataGridViewWebFields.Rows[newIndex];
                dataViewRow.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridRow.DefaultCellStyle;
                var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = dataTableRow.ItemArray;
                dataTable.Rows.Remove(dataTableRow);
                dataTableRow.Index = newIndex;
                dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, newIndex);
                //dataTable.AcceptChanges(); 
                dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
```